# Searching the values of a string in a text file and printing data related to the search values using Python

Tags: python

(Continued from my previous question; the output is a list which is used a input here)

A list

```
['35', '3', '34', '10', '34', '10', '55', '1', '55', '1', '83', '19', '55', '1', '55', '1', '16', '0', '84', '13', '25', '35']
```

is given. Now a text file with several lines of information as shown is given(mind the spaces):

```
#: 35 2 0 0 0 None
#: 35 2 1 0 0 None
#: 35 2 2 0 0 None
#: 35 2 3 0 0 None
#:     calc grain, lath: 35 3
#:     length, average, avgs: 0.00653118221089 92.7808211871 [0, 0, 0, 184.83568132297]
```

Now, using the first two values of the list i.e., 35 and 3, the text file should be searched for the occurrence of 35 and 3 in the "calc grain, lath: " line and only the value 0.00653118221089(in the immediate next line) should be returned. Note that the text file should be searched for numbers in pairs of the list i.e., the first search is 35 3, the second search is 34 10, the third search is 34 10, the fourth search is 55 1 and so on.

Any ideas how to write a Python program?

Comment: are the first 4 lines of the text file in your example relevant?

Comment: Yes they are. The first four lines starting with #: 35 2 0 0 0 None

Comment: Could you please help with a code @Ev.Kounis

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert list in below format:
list = ['35 3', '34 10', '34 10',......]

Open the file and search for line and print next line, sample code mentioned below:

```
for l in list:
    with open(newfile, 'w') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('calc grain, lath: '+l):
                     line = line.next()
                     print(line)
```

Comment: I do not need the entire line. I just need the value 0.00653118221089 as output

Comment: You can use regular expression for for this. Please refer below link.https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html